# Can I load JS before images?

Tags: javascript

I want to load the js first and the images second. Reason: I want the blue rollover affect to be applied immediately. There will eventually be double the images currently on this page so it will eventually be a bigger user experience problem as it grows.

Any ideas?

http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/

Comment: you can add javascript files in head section !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both your JS and images are linked directly from the HTML (meaning you're using the typical `<script type="javascript" src=...>` and `<image src=...>` tags) then the load order is entirely up to the user's web browser (as far as I know).

Your best chance to control the load ordering is to load the JavaScript per usual and then have custom JS to manipulate the DOM to load the images later, e.g.:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myImageHoldingDiv")
  , img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  myDiv.appendChild(img);
}
img.src = myImageUrl;
```